# unable to establish Wi-Fi connection on some wireless networks

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I'm unable to connect to only some networks (password/SSID triple check) with my default wireless adapter ***`Broadcom BCM4313 802.11b/g/n (using Proprietary driver Broadcom STA)`*** while running ***`Ubuntu 12.04`***.

In the general case I'm able to connect succesfully to any network.

However, there are at least two wireless networks I can't connect to:

- I never had any problem to connect to them before
- I changed the configuration (WPA2 instead of WEP or nothing, SSID change/hide)
- Now, when I try to connect I'm able to enter the SSID and password but the connection never establishes*

*I got the little connection animation in the status bar for ~3-5min then ubuntu prompts me for the password, tries to connect for ~3-5min, etc.

Using an ethernet wired connection, an USB Manufacturer Realtek RTL8191S WLAN Adapter, or booting on Windows and using the default adapter in those networks do not cause any problem.

**EDIT**

***`I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04`***, problem persists.

***`lspci -nn -d 14e4:`*** outputs

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

(I can't find the drivers options in ***`13.04`***)

Comment: Have you tried to run Wireshark to see what is happening when trying to connect to the networks? That might provide some clues here for you. Any output from the logs (/var/log/dmesg) might prove useful as well.

Comment: I'll tell you what I can find with wireshark

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from: lspci -nn -d 14e4:  I wonder if STA is the correct driver for your device.

Comment: @chili555 edited

Comment: @freecode Problem solved, didn't have the time to check what was going on with Wireshark.

Comment: Glad the issue is resolved, drivers can be finicky. Have a nice day Aurélien!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the Broadcom STA driver is incorrect for your device 14e4:4727. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and your wireless should be operating correctly.

Comment: Couldn't believe it, it works!

Comment: Is it possible the driver was behaving well with older technologies like WEP and broken with WPA2?

Comment: Anything is possible, I guess. Certain drivers work better with certain Broadcom devices and some not at all. In this case (14e4:4727), brcmsmac works much better.

Comment: I just tried this with the same hardware and Ubuntu 12.04 and I still get the dreaded "Authentication required by wireless network" dialog cycling.

Comment: @nomen--Please start a new question and include your kernel version: uname -r

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly when I had same problem with same driver on my old Dell Inspiron 6400 - there where 2-3 drivers and deactivating one that is not working and activating other one until find one that was correct for my hardware - solved the problem.

I hope this will help