# Broadcom wifi nightmare!

Tags: wireless, broadcom

First of all... I'm a novice with Ubuntu/Linux. I became increasingly frustrated with Windows so installed Ubuntu (12.04/32 bit). However, I'm having a torrid time trying to get the wifi to work after trying what seems like everything.

It's an HP mini with a Broadcom card (BCM4313). I know there are many threads and bits of advice but either a)it hasn't worked or b)it's jargon heavy and I have no idea what anything means.

Does anyone, in plain English, have any ideas how I can get the wifi to work?

Comment: welcome to the club. [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/253632/6228) helped me, but I do not have broadcom's chip

Comment: BЈовић's suggestion will not be effective for your Broadcom. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: lspci -nn -d 14e4: Is your device 14e4:4727? If so, please see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338391/unable-to-establish-wi-fi-connection-on-some-wireless-networks

Comment: Thanks. It is 14e4:4727 but unfortunately there is no Ethernet socket on the computer so I can't have a wired Internet connection. It's going to have to be a solution that I can copy off a USB if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Now download this package and transfer it to the desktop on a USB key or similar: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/l/linux-firmware-nonfree/linux-firmware-nonfree_1.11_all.deb  Install it from the terminal with:

```
sudo dpkg -i Desktop/linux*.deb
```

Reboot and let us have your report.