# Problem connecting to some wifi networks

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm using Dell Latitude E5530 running Ubuntu 13.04 and I have problems with connecting to some WiFi networks. While I am able to connect to most of WiFi, in some cases system is repeatedly asking me to provide WPA / WPA2 Personal password and eventually doesn't connect.

My kernel is:

```
3.8.0-33-generic
```

And my network card details are:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1681] (rev 10)
```

I've already tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338391/unable-to-establish-wi-fi-connection-on-some-wireless-networks) but it completely disabled any wifi so I went back. I am currently using `bcmwl-kernel-source` proprietary drivers.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you tried brcmsmac instead of wl, were there any informative messages here, especially about firmware? dmesg

Comment: Haven't tried it then, but now `dmesg` gives me `[    2.672591] eth1: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.20.155.1 (r326264)`.

Comment: Would you please try again the suggestion you linked, unloading wl and loading brcmsmac, and then check dmesg for any reasons it isn't working as expected?